# Overlay's height does not match_parent when adding view dynamically

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout (A), inside which I have 2 children:
- LinearLayout (B) (with some stuff) 
- below it I have another RelativeLayout (C)

I wanted to add an overlay on top of it. So all I did was added a View with match_parent as it's width and height, and transparent background. All works great, as long as I do not add views dynamically to the nested RelativeLayout (C).

When I do that my overlay stops at the last element that was not added dynamically to the RelativeLayout (C). So the height of the overlay does not match_parent anymore.

I tried to go around it, and add the overlay after I add those dynamically added views to (C), but that also didn't do the trick.

What does the trick is if I set height explicitaly to the overlay after all views are created by getting getHeight of the main root of the view. That is however not the solution I want, as I want a clean solution, that I explained above.

Currently what I did to bypass it for the moment, is I added an overlay with a humongous height(like 2000dip) and set it's bottom alignment to RelativeLayout(C). That does the trick perfectly (the effect of it), however I still would preffer to know the reason why adding dynamicaly those views does not update the height of the overlay (also if I add it dynamically after previous views).

Just to mention, I tried to do requestLayout(), invalidate(), and postInvalidate() on the main container after all views were added. No change.

ps. Might be important piece of information: this root RelativeLayout stated in the beginning is inside a LinearLayout, which is a single child of a ScrollView